# postgresql c-extension loads another external library

Tags: c++, c, postgresql, linker, phash

I need to compare pHashes (phash.org) with a hamming distance function.

I tried the one from pg_similarity, but it doesn't seem to work right. (identical pHashes don't have a hamming distance of 0).

So I figured I'd just use a c-extension to use the `ph_hamming_distance` function that's part of the pHash library.

What I've got:
phash.c

```
#include <postgres.h>
#include <pHash.h>
#include <fmgr.h>
#include <utils/bytea.h>
#include <utils/datum.h>

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(phash_hamming);
Datum phash_hamming(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {

    bytea *bytea1 = PG_GETARG_BYTEA_P(0);
    bytea *bytea2 = PG_GETARG_BYTEA_P(1);
    //FIXME - length of bytea1 & bytea2 must be 4 bytes (64bits)

    ulong64 long1 = *((ulong64*) bytea1);
    ulong64 long2 = *((ulong64*) bytea2);

    int32 ret = ph_hamming_distance(long1, long2);

    PG_RETURN_INT32(ret);
}
```

Makefile

```
CXXFLAGS=-I/usr/include/postgresql/server
LDFLAGS=-Bstatic -lpHash
all: phash.o

phash.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -fpic -c phash.c
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o phash.so phash.o

install:
    cp phash.so `pg_config --pkglibdir`

clean:
    rm -f phash.o phash.so
```

SQL

```
 CREATE FUNCTION phash_hamming (bytea1 bytea, bytea2 bytea) RETURNS int AS '$libdir/phash' LANGUAGE C;
```

Error that I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/phash.so": /usr/lib/postgresql/phash.so: undefined symbol: _Z16pg_detoast_datumP7varlena
```

I must not be linking right to postgresql somehow?

Comment: sorry, should have googled first, it's a C++/C linking problem, still don't know the solution yet though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an old question, but...

1. There is no need to add extra wrapper file and compile it using gcc.
2. You need extern "C" both PostgreSQL headers and PostgreSQL macros.

   ```
   extern "C" {
     #include <postgres.h>
     #include <fmgr.h>
     #ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
     PG_MODULE_MAGIC
     #endif
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still convinced there might be a better way but this is what I did that worked.

(I will add range-checking, instead of just assuming all bytea's are 4-bytes... eventually, leaving a potential segfault in production would be bad, so it's a good thing this is just a toy project)

phash.c - pure C file, compiled with gcc

```
#include <postgres.h>
#include <fmgr.h>
#include <utils/bytea.h>
#include <utils/datum.h>

//typedef unsigned __int64 ulong64;
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
typedef unsigned __int64 ulong64;
#else
typedef unsigned long long ulong64;
#endif

extern int32 c_ph_hamming_distance (ulong64 b1, ulong64 b2);

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(phash_hamming);
Datum phash_hamming(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {

    bytea *bytea1 = PG_GETARG_BYTEA_P(0);
    bytea *bytea2 = PG_GETARG_BYTEA_P(1);
    //FIXME - length of bytea1 & bytea2 must be 4 bytes (64bits)

    ulong64 long1 = *((ulong64*) bytea1);
    ulong64 long2 = *((ulong64*) bytea2);

    int32 ret = c_ph_hamming_distance(long1, long2);

    PG_RETURN_INT32(ret);
}
```

phash_wrapper.cpp - make convert a version of ph_hamming_distance with c-linking instead of cpp linking (compiled with g++)

```
#include <pHash.h>
extern "C" {
    int c_ph_hamming_distance (ulong64 b1, ulong64 b2){
        return ph_hamming_distance(b1, b2);
    }
}
```

Makefile

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/postgresql/server
LDFLAGS=-lpHash
all: phash.so

phash_wrapper.o: phash_wrapper.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -fpic -c phash_wrapper.cpp

phash.o: phash.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fpic -c phash.c

phash.so: phash.o phash_wrapper.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -shared -o phash.so phash.o phash_wrapper.o

install:
    cp phash.so `pg_config --pkglibdir`

clean:
    rm -f phash.o phash.so phash_wrapper.o
```

SQL - the same

```
CREATE FUNCTION phash_hamming (bytea1 bytea, bytea2 bytea) RETURNS int AS '$libdir/phash' LANGUAGE C;
```

Comment: seems about right, for when you need a pure-C application (postgresql) calling a C++ library, you need something to bridge from C conventions to C++ conventions. You might be able to get away with putting the declaration of your extension function in an `extern "C"` block rather than needing two files, though?